# How to avoid to hardcoded cast from context to activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, pass-by-reference, android-context

I have MainActivity.kt with passing an activity context to **MyObj**-class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MyObj.processing(this)
    }
}
```

MyObj.kt:

```
class MyObj {
    companion object {
        fun processing( cx:Context ) {

            // -- doesnt work (universal way)
            val intent = cx.intent

            // -- i have to cast context to activity via hardcoded way (not universal)
            val intent = (cx as MainActivity).intent
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to have an universal MyObj without a need to cast in a manual way. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried to declare the function argument as the type you want?

Comment: @Chris I thought I must pass strict only context

Comment: Avoid as much as possible passing Context around. It has lifecycle and accessing it outside of its lifecycle will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Change Context to Activity your function will be like this:

```
 fun processing( ac:Activity ) {

            val intent = ac.intent

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it would be better not to cast anything, but rather pass in the relevant data i.e. Intent in your case:

```
fun processing (intent: Intent) {

     // TODO do your stuff with intent

        }
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike! Yes, I considered this variant. But very often I need get more data from activity (in this case, Intent - only for example).

Comment: @IgorAntoshkin if you need an `Activity`, make the parameter's type `Activity`! Be as specific as you can be - there are `Context`s that aren't `Activities`, but if your function allows you to pass in a non-Activity Context, you'll get a crash when you try to cast it. Explicit casting like that is often a sign you're not using the type system properly - you usually shouldn't *need* to tell the compiler what type an object is